# Haskell foldr1 lambda function which adds tuple values

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, tuples, fold

I have been scratching my head trying to figure this out. How do I use foldr1 (or any other fold for that matter) in order to get the sum of tuples in a list.

**Example:**

```
list = [(1,2), (3,4)]
sum = 10
```

I've tried `foldr1 (\x y -> fst(x) + snd(x) + y) [(1,2),(3,4)]` but it doesn't work and I suspect that it has to do with the the types being created while executing the fold not being tuples.

When I run the command described above I get this:

```
foldr1 (\x y -> fst(x) + snd(x) + y) [(1,2),(3,4)]

• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ (a, a)
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘y’
      In the expression: fst (x) + snd (x) + y
      In the first argument of ‘foldr1’, namely
        ‘(\ x y -> fst (x) + snd (x) + y)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        y :: (a, a) (bound at <interactive>:30:12)
        x :: (a, a) (bound at <interactive>:30:10)
        it :: (a, a) (bound at <interactive>:30:1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the fold function not meant for this (I've solved this using sum and map together and it got the right answer)?

Comment: you can not use `foldr1`, since the first item is a 2-tuple, so then `y` would be a 2-tuple as well.

Comment: Compare the types of `foldr` and `foldr1`: the former takes a function of type `a -> b -> b`, the latter of type `a -> a -> a`.

Comment: One piece of advice: write type signatures. I know it can be hard when you're starting out, but you'll have to learn it at some point and it can make error messages much easier to understand. In this case if you wrote your summation function under the type `[(Int, Int)] -> Int` then you wouldn't get that confusing "infinite type" error message.

Comment: nit: In Haskell we usually don't use parentheses with function calls: `fst(x) + snd(x) + y` → `fst x + snd x + y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a` is meant for when the result of the fold is the same type as the elements of the list. Since your result is a number and the list elements are tuples it isn't the right function here. `foldr` is probably the correct one:

```hs
foldr (\x y -> fst(x) + snd(x) + y) 0 [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Answer (score 5):

you can not use `foldr1`, since the first item is a 2-tuple, so then `y` would be a 2-tuple as well.

You can use `foldr` instead:

```
foldr (\x y -> fst(x) + snd(x) + y) 0 [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

or simpler:

```
foldr (\(x1, x2) y -> x1 + x2 + y) 0 [(1,2),(3,4)]
```